# How to set the Severity as Error in GCP alert page using Terraform GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-logging, gcp-alerts

I am setting up for IaC in Terraform for Google cloud function when error occurs.

This is my code in Terraform:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "my_cf_alert_policy" {
    display_name = "${var.ENVIRONMENT}_my_cf_error_alert"
    notification_channels = [
        google_monitoring_notification_channel.email_channel.name
        ]
    combiner     = "OR"
    conditions {
        display_name = "send_alert_when_severity=ERROR"
        condition_matched_log {
            filter = "resource.type=\"cloud_function\" resource.labels.function_name=\"${google_cloudfunctions_function.my_cf.name}\" severity=\"ERROR\""
        }
    }

    alert_strategy {
        auto_close = "604800s"
        notification_rate_limit {
            period = "300s"
        }
    }
}
```

but when I see the same alert policy in GCP console, I could see the Severity is `No severity` as attached.

[image]

I need to have Severity set to  `Error`.

Comment: It's because you're confusing the severity of the logs that should be filtered with the *severity* of the alert. Read https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy#severity

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `severity` field in the `google_monitoring_alert_policy` block. This code should work:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  display_name = "Error alert"
  severity = "ERROR"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "Condition 1"
    condition_matched_log {
            filter = "resource.type=\"cloud_function\" resource.labels.function_name=\"demo-cf\" severity=\"ERROR\""
    }
  }

  alert_strategy {
    notification_rate_limit {
        period = "300s"
    }
  }

  notification_channels = [data.google_monitoring_notification_channel.email.name]

}
```

For log-based metrics, you need to specify the `notification_rate_limit` field.

FYI. `notificationChannelStrategy` is not allowed for log-based alerts

Comment: Hi @Gang Chen, Thanks for your response. May I know what is the issue with my notification channel configuration?

Comment: hmm, your original code now doesn't have the `notificationChannelStrategy` field, will update my response. Context: when using log based alerts (metrics), `notificationChannelStrategy` is not configurable when creating alert.

Comment: Hi @Gang Chen, Still not clear about `notificationChannelStrategy`. you also used same notification channel in your code. still thinkng what is wrong in my code related to `notificationChannel`. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting an error with above suggestion. `Unsupported argument`. seems this statement is not supported `severity = "ERROR"`